# Reading a file from line 4 to the end

Tags: awk, shell

I want to read a file from the line 4 to the very end is there anyway to this with awk or something?

Answer (score 8):

This sed command will do:

```
sed -n '4,$p' file.txt
```

Or using awk:

```
awk 'NR>=4' file.txt
```

Or using tail:

```
tail +4 file.txt
```

Comment: `tail +4 file.txt` is another way to get the same result.

Comment: tail +4 is the simplest, add it to the solution!

Comment: Or sed 1,3d but tail +4 beats it by 1 char.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NR >= 4 {print $0}'
```

For example

```
$> seq 101 110 | awk 'NR >= 4 {print $0}'
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
```

Comment: This will skip line 4. It should either be `awk 'NR>3' filename` or `awk 'NR>=4' filename`. OP wants to read from line 4.

Answer (score 0):

`tail +4 filename` ll serve ur purpose.

more on [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score -1):

heres a method (that can depend on the type of shell you use, bash should work):

```
tmpvar=`cat a_file | wc -l `; tail -$((tmpvar-4)) a_file
```

heres another method that should work in more shells:

```
 cat a_file -n | awk '{if($1>4) print $2}'
```

Comment: Couldn't have made any more complicated. :)